# How to prevent the program asking use to enter a number each time the user enter a number?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageMaxMin 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double maxium = 0;
        double minium = 100;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit： ");
        double input = kb.nextDouble();

         while (input != -1)
            {

             while ((input > 100) || (input <= -1))
              {
                 System.out.println(" Invalid! Please enter a value between 0 and 100, -1 to show the result: ");
                 input = kb.nextDouble();
              }

                count++;             
                sum += input; 

                if (maxium < input)
                {
                    maxium = input;
                }

                if (minium > input)
                {
                    minium = input;
                }


                System.out.println("Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit： ");
                input = kb.nextDouble();

            }
                double average = (sum / count);  
                System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
                System.out.println("The maxium is: " + maxium);
                System.out.println("The minium is: " + minium);

    }

}
```

When I run the code, when the user enter a number, and want to enter another number, this pop up each time "Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit： ".

For example:
Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit： 
100
Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit： 
0
Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit： 
-1
The average is: 50.0
The maxium is: 100.0
The minium is: 0.0

I want to be able to let the user enter a list of enter without this "Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit： " popping up each time.

Example:
100 
0
-1
The average is: 50.0
The maxium is: 100.0
The minium is: 0.0

Please help me out.
New to programming

Comment: What do you think System.out.println does?

Answer (score 2):

Change your style of loop to use a `do-while` loop instead of `while-loop`.

Basically, you want to enter the loop cycle at least once, for example...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double maxium = 0;
        double minium = 100;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        double input = -1;
        // Main processing loop...
        do {

            // Validation loop...
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit: ");
                input = kb.nextDouble();
                kb.nextLine();
            } while (input > 100);

            if (input > -1) {
                count++;
                sum += input;

                if (maxium < input) {
                    maxium = input;
                }

                if (minium > input) {
                    minium = input;
                }
            }
        } while (input != -1);

        double average = (sum / count);

        System.out.println(
                        "The average is: " + average);
        System.out.println(
                        "The maxium is: " + maxium);
        System.out.println(
                        "The minium is: " + minium);

    }

}
```

This does use two loops, you could reduce it to one and ignore any values which are out of range, for example...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double maxium = 0;
        double minium = 100;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        double input = -1;
        do {

            System.out.println("Please enter a value between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit: ");
            input = kb.nextDouble();
            kb.nextLine();

            if (input > -1 && input <= 100) {
                count++;
                sum += input;

                if (maxium < input) {
                    maxium = input;
                }

                if (minium > input) {
                    minium = input;
                }
            }
        } while (input != -1);

        double average = (sum / count);

        System.out.println(
                        "The average is: " + average);
        System.out.println(
                        "The maxium is: " + maxium);
        System.out.println(
                        "The minium is: " + minium);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the line printing that message inside the first while loop, at the end of it, just before the input.

Comment: Well he said he doesn't want the message to print every time. So that's my answer. I didn't put the code because I'm using the android app and I don't know if I can. But I could have been clearer.